# What does the notation $\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ mean?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, notation

This is coming up on one of my topology assignments and I have never seen this before. My best guess would be that it's the collection of binary strings of countable length. If anyone could explain this, I'd appreciate it a lot!

Comment: The set of applications from $\Bbb N$ into $\{0,1\}$, that is, the set of sequences whose entries are 0 or 1.

Comment: Just as you can think of $\{0,1\}^3$ as the functions from $\{1,2,3\} \to \{0,1\}$ you can think of $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{N}$ as functions from $\mathbb{N} \to \{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

More generally, $B^A$ is the set of functions from $A$ to $B$.  The motivation for this notation is that if $A$ and $B$ are finite, $|B^A|=|B|^{|A|}$.

Answer (score 1):

Being more accurate it is the set of all infinite sequences with entries being $0$ or $1$. The general rule is given in the answer above. For Example $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is a set of all infinite sequances of natural numbers. The interesting think is that some set theorists would instantly call $\lbrace 0,1\rbrace^\mathbb{N}$ a Cantor set.